# How to draw a multi-color USA state map with Geo entities?

Tags: graphics

Needed to draw a salesman territory map, multicolor like a schoolhouse USA states map, with the Postal Abbreviation location at the state capital. Wished to do it with GeoGraphics and curated geography information already in modern Mathematica systems.

[image: USA state map]

Comment: That's neat! Is there some meaning behind the colours chosen for each state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite smoothly in a few lines of code:

```
GeoGraphics[
 {GeoStyling[Opacity@1, EdgeForm[Gray], 
     FaceForm[RandomChoice@{LightGreen, LightBlue, LightRed, Yellow}]],
    Polygon@#,
    Text[Style[#["StateAbbreviation"], 
      FontSize -> 7], #["CapitalCity"]["Position"]]} & /@ 
  EntityList[
   EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "ContinentalUSStates"]], 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: outstanding, so lovely, so much functionality from so little code

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G Glad you like it :) Do you understand what's going on in the code, or would you like some more explanation?

Comment: Using help on the keywords, I should be OK, thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Below has some extra code for a shorthand for Reap into a list, also a pattern for datasets with a logical primary key.
May have gone overboard with the `Normal`, as I am not yet completely comfortable with `Association` and `Dataset`.

```
reapList::usage="gracefully collect all Sow expressions into list, same shape even if empty";
SetAttributes[reapList,HoldAll];
reapList[r__]:=Flatten[Reap[r,{_}][[2]],2]

allUSAStatesList={
    "stateAbbreviation"->#[EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision","StateAbbreviation"]],
    "name"->StringSplit[#[EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision","Name"]],", "][[1]],
    "entityMA"->#,
    "captialCityCoordinates"->#[EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision","CapitalCity"]][EntityProperty["City","Coordinates"]],
    "polygon"->Polygon[#]
   }&/@EntityValue[Entity["Country","UnitedStates"],"AdministrativeDivisions"];
"";

allUSAStatesDataset=Dataset[Association[#]&/@allUSAStatesList];
allUSAStates[s_String]:=First@Select[allUSAStatesDataset,#stateAbbreviation===s&];
allUSAStates[k_String,col_String]:=allUSAStates[k][col];
allUSAStates[All]:=Association[#->allUSAStates[#]&/@(Sort@Normal@allUSAStatesDataset[All,"stateAbbreviation"])];
allUSAStates[All,col_String]:=Association[#->allUSAStates[#][col]&/@(Sort@Normal@allUSAStatesDataset[All,"stateAbbreviation"])]

f01[statekey_String->a_]:=(
  Sow@GeoStyling[EdgeForm[Gray],RandomChoice@{LightGreen,LightBlue,LightRed,Yellow}];
  Sow@a["polygon"];
 )

f02[statekey_String->a_]:=(
  Sow@GeoMarker[a["captialCityCoordinates"],Text@Style[a["stateAbbreviation"],Black]]
 )

GeoGraphics@With[
  {lower48=DeleteCases[Normal@allUSAStates[All],("HI"|"AK")->_]},
  reapList[
   f01/@lower48;
   f02/@lower48
  ]
 ]
```

Output is above in question.